# What is the difference between a Custom Build Step and a Post-Build Event?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, post-build-event, custom-build-step

Both project settings allow me to execute custom commands. What are the benefits or drawbacks of each?

Comment: Related: [Visual Studio: Run C++ project Post-Build Event even if project is up-to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1937702/3258851)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Big difference.  A custom build step allows you to specify dependencies and outputs.  Which allows the build system to determine *when* to execute the step and to skip it when the output is already up to date.  A post-build event is *always* executed when the project requires building and its timing is fixed.

Comment: re: **A post-build event is always executed** >>< As a test I added `echo HELLO WORLD` to my *Post-Build Event*. (1) `HELLO WORLD` is displayed as expected. (2) If I simply right-click *Build* on my project again... `HELLO WORLD` is not displayed in the *Visual Studio Output, Show output from Build window*.  (3) Executing *Clean* followed by *Build*... and `HELLO WORLD` appears again. So it appears that in Visual Studio 2012 (with *Platform Tooolset* set to v90 in project configuration)... **the post-build event only executes when something is actually built.**  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

seems @Hans answer got it switched, main difference is that if no files need to be built, no build events will occur.

---

from the msdn documentation:

Build events and custom build steps run in the following order along with other build steps:

```
Pre-Build event
Custom build tools on individual files
MIDL
Resource compiler
The C/C++ compiler
Pre-Link event
Linker or Librarian (as appropriate)
Manifest Tool
BSCMake
Custom build step on the project
Post-Build event
```

The custom build step on the project and a post-build event run sequentially after all other build processes finish.

**Build events are executed only if the build successfully reaches those points in the build process**. If an error occurs in the build, the post-build event will not occur; if the error occurs before the linking phase, neither the pre-link nor the post-build event will occur. Additionally, if no files need to be linked, the pre-link event will not occur. The pre-link event is also not available in projects that do not contain a link step.
**If no files need to be built, no build events will occur.**

From within the Visual Studio C++ development environment, there are three basic ways to customize the build process:

**Custom Build Steps**
A custom build step is a build rule associated with a project. A custom build step can specify a command line to execute, any additional input or output files, and a message to display. For more information, see How to: Add a Custom Build Step to MSBuild Projects.

**Custom Build Tools**
A custom build tool is a build rule associated with one or more files. A custom build step can pass input files to a custom build tool, which results in one or more output files. For example, the help files in an MFC application are built with a custom build tool. For more information, see How to: Add Custom Build Tools to MSBuild Projects and Specifying Custom Build Tools.
Build Events

**Build events** let you customize a project's build. There are three build events: pre-build, pre-link, and post-build. A build event lets you specify an action to occur at a specific time in the build process. For example, you could use a build event to register a file with regsvr32.exe after the project finishes building. For more information, see Specifying Build Events.