# Enforcing custom build step in VS 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I have annoying problem in VS 2005. C++ project have custom build steps. However VS does not execute it none of the C++ source files changed. And I need to execute it even if one non-related (say text) file changed in the project. What to do?

Comment: What about using a Build-Event instead a Build-Step?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in this answer: [Visual Studio: Run C++ project Post-Build Event even if project is up-to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937702/visual-studio-run-c-project-post-build-event-even-if-project-is-up-to-date)

You can use the Custom Build Steps with a non-existing file as output.

Comment: Standard practice is to vote to close the question as a duplicate, not post another answer with a link. You have the [requisite rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) to do so. It automatically leaves a comment with your suggestion.