# Create Visual Studio "Custom Build Step" with CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I would like to run a code generator every time my project is built in Visual Studio, even if no source file in the project was changed. Therefore I would like to have a custom build step set up as explained in [Visual Studio: Run C++ project Post-Build Event even if project is up-to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937702/visual-studio-run-c-project-post-build-event-even-if-project-is-up-to-date).

How can I create such a build step with CMake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a custom target is what you are looking for: [add_custom_target](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:add_custom_target)

From the documentation:

> Add a target with no output so it will always be built.

Or if you are generating a code file,

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:add_custom_target

can be run `POST_BUILD` and generate output.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a possibility to fail the Visual Studio build if my custom target (I chose option 1) fails? The return code seems to have no effect?

Comment: I don't know for sure, I use a Linux system. But on my machine, if the command used in the target returns non-zero, the build fails and if it returns zero is works. So it could be a VS+CMake issue, or it could be a problem with the version of CMake you are using. I don't own any Windows machines to try!

Answer (score 1):

This is afaik not possible with CMake, and is therefore ***a missing feature*** for sure.

The answer from Tarydon in the question you refer to, is about setting up precisely what you want - a "**Custom Build Step**". This means that you still only have your main target (VS Project), with something that looks like a "**Post-Build Event**" but technically isn't, since Post-Build Events  aren't run if the project is up-to-date.

The answer from tpg2114 works, but has one major drawback; it spams your solution with phony projects. In case you have a hundred projects in a solution, having to add another hundred just as post-build wrappers to the first hundred is of course undesirable.

Depending on your situation, it might sometimes be easier to use Post-Build Events and force a rebuild of at least one source file, for the project to actually build and therefore also run your custom command.