# VS 2010 - Always execute pre-build event

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In my solution I have a project with an attached pre-build event to check if certain files need to be regenerated. This all works fine if something changed in the project (or dependent projects). However, if nothing changed the pre-build event is not triggered.

Is there a way to run the pre-build event everytime VS tries to build a project (even if it is clean from a code file standpoint)?

Alternatively, is there any other way to run a script first before building a project so that I can regenerate my files first?

Comment: The point is, build doesn't even start if there are no code changes, so build events never have a chance to execute.

Comment: I'd also be interested in alternative solutions. Question edited.

Comment: You could use `makefile project` [(msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/txcwa2xx.aspx). It allows to run any commands on `build`, `rebuild` and `clean`

Comment: makefile project is no option, this is a big VS solution with almost 60 project, integrated into CI builds and all that. I need a solution on project level.

Comment: [For cpp projects you can use custom build steps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937702/visual-studio-run-c-project-post-build-event-even-if-project-is-up-to-date). Do you need it for other project types?

Comment: Johny, can you post your comment as answer? A custom build for the source file from which the other files are generated is indeed the right solution.

Comment: @johny, do you want the points for your hint? Then please post it as answer.

Comment: @MikeLischke excuse me for delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a `Visual C++` project you may specify `Command Line` in the `Custom build step` (`Configuration Properties` - `Custom build step`) and leave the field `Outputs` empty. It will be executed even if the project has no changes.

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937702/visual-studio-run-c-project-post-build-event-even-if-project-is-up-to-date) is the similar question.

Comment: As of VS2019 this no longer works.  Visual studio issues a warning "No outputs specified for item "...".  Its custom build command will be skipped."  Edit: just realized this answer was for custom build step, not custom build tool.  I haven't tried custom build tools.

Comment: Amending my previous comment further: looks like there's a setting to "Verify Inputs and Outputs Exist" that you can disable to get the above working.